# access file from Laravel request inside a queue job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

Hello everyone I have a `queued` Laravel `job` that runs to `insert some records in the database for an imported file by a user`. but whenever I access the request object to get the `uploaded file` from inside the `job` I got `null`. however, the file is `received` in the `controller` normally. any idea?

find the import method below in the controller

```
 public function import(ImportPointRequest $request)
    {
        Storage::makeDirectory('import_logs');
        $file        = request()->file('file');
        $fileName    = 'importlog_date_' . date('Y-m-d') . '-user_' . auth()->id() . '.xlsx';
        $logFile     = 'import_logs/' . $fileName;
        $readerTypes = ['xlsx' => Excel::XLSX, 'xls' => Excel::XLS, 'csv' => Excel::CSV];
        $link        = route('file.show', ['import_logs', $fileName]);

        try {
            ExcelFacade::import(new PointsImportHeading(), $file);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->returnBadRequest(config('point.error-codes.import-fail'), $e->getMessage());
        }

        (new PointsImport(auth()->user(), auth()->user()->account_id, $logFile))->queue(
            $file->getRealPath(),
            null,
            $readerTypes[request()->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension()]
        )->chain([new AfterImportJob(auth()->id(), $logFile, $link)]);

        return $this->returnSuccess(trans('point::point.import-queued', ['module' => trans('point::point.point')]));
    }
```

find the getImportedFileContent method below in the job

```
   protected function getUploadedFileContent(): array
    { 
         return Excel::toArray(new PointsImportHeading(), request()->file('file'));
    }
```

The problem in this part `request()->file('file')` always returns null.

Comment: Jobs are dispatched to a queue for the server to run away from the request this is why `request()` will be empty. This is done to speed up the response to the user and execute logic away from the request. You need to store that file somewhere and later read from it inside of your job. [Read more about Queues in the Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues)

Comment: Yes that's absolutely right thanks for sharing that info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not true. In Laravel, the request lifecycle is started when a request comes to your server and it ends as soon as a response is sent back to the user's browser. When you queue a job in Laravel, it means that job will be processed later, perhaps even on a different server. When the job actually runs, the original request lifecycle is already over. Therefore, you cannot access the request data inside your queued job.

If you need to use the uploaded file in your queued job, you'll need to store the uploaded file in a location where your job can access it. This could be on your server's file system or on a cloud storage service.

In your controller, you're already storing the file temporarily to process it with Excel:

```
$file = request()->file('file');
```

However, you don't persist the file, which is why the file is not available when the job runs. You need to store the file somewhere more permanently.

After store your file permanently you can read the file from the new location.

Comment: You're absolutely right thanks for the explanation